# How to repeat a key in mac while holding down?

Tags: keyboard

I've tried searching for an app or tools that can do this in macOS but I couldn't find any.

There seems to be a key repeat setting in system prefs but it seems to have no effect. For example in notes, if I hold a key it would not repeat?

Ideally I can have the key repeat behaviour on and off as I only want it during the day for work activities

Comment: No I'm looking for a way to do this

Comment: & the linked question gives exactly the same answer as below.

Answer (score 2):

There is a terminal command to set the option. Go to terminal and type

`defaults write -g ApplePressAndHoldEnabled -bool false`

This actually turns it on. You have to restart your computer for this to take effect.  You turn it off by typing the same line with true instead of false.

`defaults write -g ApplePressAndHoldEnabled -bool true`

Comment: And then the settings like speed in system prefs will take effect? If so, is there a way to have app specific settings?

Comment: No, this is a global switch, reboot to toggle.

Comment: yes. then the speed and delay can be adjusted from the system preferences.  There is no way to do this for a specific app.

Comment: You would think that Apple would expose this in Settings to repeat keys or not. Seems silly.